# How to use optional params in a Action?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, action, parameters

Probably something simple I overlooked how do I fix this?

Note: compiler generates 0 errors yet it doesn't build

```
    /**
     * The action (optional object[] is the params)
     */
    private Action<object[]> action;

    /**
     * Parameters
     */
    private object[] parameters;

    public virtual void runAction() //<- this is overridable
    {
        action(parameters);
    }

    public void setAction(Action action)
    {
        this.action<null> = action<null>;
    }

    public void setAction(Action action, params object[] parameters)
    {
        this.parameters = this.parameters;
        this.action<parameters> = action<parameters>;
    }
```

Maybe there is a way I can make this even without `object[] parameters` even..

I call `runAction` outside this class. there are many classes like this in List all I call `runAction` method. I generate these classes on demend. This class contains a bunch more logic then just what you see.

Let me know thanks I appreciate the support.

Comment: Huh? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: "compiler generates 0 errors yet it doesn't build" -- I felt it deserved a quote.

Comment: It's acting like custom Event with much changed logic, well it's true Blindy lol, well i'm a newbie just trying to fix my mistakes.

Comment: How often does something like this happen.. where you get absolutely no errors in the Error List yet attempt to build the solution it doesn't work. I don't understand whats so funny about that.. but anyways I updated the question to make explain logic a bit more.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just unchecked the button that shows errors in your error window? Maybe it's only showing warnings...

Comment: Nope check it out, http://i.imgur.com/SxSNN.png the [(X) 0 Errors] box is highlighted is that what you mean? .. if i make some stupid syntax error, then a error pops out! http://i.imgur.com/SxSNN.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> this.action<parameters> = action<parameters>;
> ```

This is a mess.  `action` isn't a generic type or generic method, so this isn't supplying a generic parameter (and anyway, generic parameters are types, not variables.  You're actually somehow using the less-than and greater-than relational operators?  But `parameters > ;` doesn't compare anything.

The compiler is absolutely right not to let this build.  It seems like this would be what you want:

```
private Action action;

public virtual void runAction()
{
    action();
}

public void setAction(Action action)
{
    this.action = action;
}

public void setAction(Action<object[]> action, params object[] parameters)
{
    this.action = delegate { action(parameters) };
}
```

I recommend that you read about "closures".  You might find that this class you're writing isn't very useful at all.

Comment: Whats wrong with 'this.action = action?'  I pass a action using lambda to setAction() so obviously i'll have to assign it to another action it's a reference after all? or what

Comment: @SSpoke: You might have seen my answer while the code was getting scrambled by HTML processing, it's fixed now.

Comment: Never heard of closures have to check it out. How will it replace what I'm trying to do.. can I store variables in it? even more can I reuse logic? (most of the logic in this class is reused. I checked it out.. seems it only talks about delegates? It lets you return functions? from inside functions then use them again seems very complicated probably something i'll never use. They got recursion for that

Comment: How do I use the bottom setAction like..   `setAction(() => { ..code.. }, "first param", "second", "etc");`

Comment: @SSpoke: Why don't you just put the parameters INSIDE the lambda and let it capture them?  Then you can get rid of `params object[] parameters` and just use the standard `Action`.  If you define a lambda that needs no arguments (`() =>` ...) then why are you trying to give it arguments?

Comment: Well if i get rid of parameters setAction method can I still be able to use `() => ..` or i will have to `use (null) => ..` if no params needed ? thats what i'm trying to avoid it looks to ugly. I dont even know how to use arguments in lambda without using arrows or something.

Comment: Ben I'd like to add I cannot use Lambda variables it gives me errors in the way I want to use them. `A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else` Say I want to do something like this.. (changing variable names isn't a option.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("regular Loop i = " + i);
                Event newEvent = new Event(3000);
                newEvent.setAction((int i) => i => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Event loop I =" + i);
                });
                events.Add(newEvent);
            }`

Comment: @SSpoke: Changing variable names is going to have to be an option, or else you'll capture the loop variable and end up printing `10` instead of whatever `i` was when the loop ran.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: @SSpoke: I would write that as: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { int current_i = i; Console.WriteLine("regular Loop i = " + i); Event newEvent = new Event(3000); newEvent.setAction(new delegate { Console.WriteLine("Event loop I = " + current_i); }); events.Add(newEvent); }` and then you can use a simple `Action` with no parameters.

Comment: Yes... Ben thats what I think i'll stick too.. (thats actually how I had it before I wanted to try the parameters idea out).. but then it hit me.. the parameters idea might never work. man there is no way to keep the value final? without copying it?

Comment: @SSpoke: I don't see how copying the value into the `parameters` array was supposed to be better than copying it into the captured variable.  Actually I think the `parameters` array is much worse, since it needs boxing.

Comment: yes you are right again i'll stick to what I got. While I still got contact without I guess I could ask you another question without making a new question. It's about LinkedList vs List I read linkedlist is a pointer node list etc.. atm I'm using a List for a operation which just populates the list.. then loops it from beginning to end. Then it adds that whole list to very end of another list which had previous objects on it which also loops from start to end to do something. At the end the first list gets cleared and repeats it's job. Think I should switch to LinkedList. Thanks again for help

Comment: @SSpoke: LinkedList really only has an advantage when you're frequently adding or removing from the middle of a list.  Everything you described should be very fast with a normal List.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `Action` supports a variable number of parameters. I would think you could just do:

```
public void RunAction(Action<object[]> action, params object[] parameters)
{
    action(parameters);
}
```

which would end up being used something like:

```
RunAction( x =>
  {
     Assert.AreEqual("Param1", x[0]);
     Assert.AreEqual("Param2", x[1]);
  },
  "Param1",
  "Param2");
```

Or am I missing something in what you are trying to do?

Comment: ya.. spot on answer.. same with Ben Voigt but I guess I'll accept his answer he answered first. Actually you know what.. I don't know why hes is using a delegate and you are not and both work? i'll think i'll accept your answer seems like less processing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VS 2010, and .Net 4.0?  ... try

```
public void setAction(Action action, object[] parameters = null)     
{
    this.parameters = this.parameters;    
    this.action<parameters> = action<parameters>;     
}
```

You are creating an 'optional' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use an optional parameter so that you can have a shorter call when you don't need the additional parameter, and you're just working with 1 - 2 parameters you can do the following:

1. Define two actions, one that accepts the first parameter, and one that accepts the two parameters (e.g.):

   ```
   private readonly Action<EventType> _updateLog;

   private readonly Action<EventType, string> _updateLogWithDescription;
   ```
2. Once you instantiate the action, just assign the action with two parameters as the input parameter, and calculate the action with one parameter based on calling the other action and giving it the default parameters, e.g.:

   ```
   public MyClass(Action<EventType, string> updateLogWithDescription)
   {
       _updateLogWithDescription = updateLogWithDescription;
       _updateLog = (EventType eventType) => updateLogWithDescription(eventType, string.Empty);
   }
   ```

You will then just need to worry about 1 source action that does all the internal computation, and then in the class that you are actually calling the actions you will simply use the two instances as you need them:

```
   _updateLog(EventType.MyEvent);
   _updateLogWithDescription(EventType.MyOtherEvent, $"My custom data {myvalue}");
```

I preferred to use this as my solution, as I really don't like to mess about with `object[]` and casting.